# Adding optional var to URL

Tags: php

I'd like to add an optional variable to a redirect URL if that variable is present. Here's what I mean:

I have a URL on my site:

> mydomain.com/myPage?rel=abc

Later in my PHP I need to detect if a variable is set, get both the name of the variable and its value and add those to my redirect URL:

> redirectdomain.com/somePage?rel=abc

Why do I need my script to do that and not just add it in my code? Because the variable may not be present, or its name maybe something else, like **userId**, or **acticle** etc... It may even have multiple variables:

> redirectdomain.com/somePage?rel=abc&ref=123

I'm not really sure how can I get those from a current URL. I was able to get those elements by using:

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']
```

I suppose I could explode the string and then get the pairs?.. A bit confused.

Comment: Your question is not clear can you please teel what is your expected output and what you wana check exactly. A bit confusion at end ?

Comment: if you don't know what the var's name is, how do you expect to be able to tell that var from any other var in the url? what makes `foo=bar` relevant, but `baz=qux` irrelevant?

Comment: I don't think you want string, because you can get the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string of the URL is available in teh $_SERVER global.   Do this to turn it into an array, then parse the array, or just transfer the whole string.

This example will copy the exact string...

```
$mynewURL = 'redirect.com?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

This example will give you an array to work with.

```
$somevar = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

If you only wanted to include certain variables in the redirect you could do this ... (lets say you wanted userId and Fullname only and ignore any other variables passed in the URL)

```
$redirect = 'redirect.com?';
foreach ($somevar as $v) {
   $temparr = explode('=', $v);
   $redirect .= array_search($temparr[0], $temparr) == 'userId' || array_search($temparr[0], $temparr) == 'Fullname' ? $v : '';
}
```

Comment: Possibly because I use rewrite rule in my .htaccess I get nothing when I try $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] however this one works well $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']

Comment: Does redirect query string work ?   like you posted in your question?  you can use the same code in my question to parse that out with explode.  I'm sure you already know how to do that.  So is the URL when you get to the page showing the query string ?

Comment: What does this return if anything ?   $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: When you re-write the URL are you re-writing the query string as well ?

Comment: No, I actually followed your advise: grabbed all vars, removed initial page name value (rewrite rule) , stripped '&', added a check for ? in the redirect URL, and created connector ?/& based on the check, then hooked it all together. No need to get var names or values. If they exist, as many as they could be, they'll be tagged to the redirect URL. If not, just redirect without additional vars.

Comment: Very nice.  You should edit your question and add the solution you used in case anyone else comes by the page they may be able to use your solution.

Comment: There was a lot more to this than just the query string.  There was re-write rule to contend with etc...  Your a bit late to the party,  the green checkmark means this questions all done being answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **parse_url();** PHP function to get all vars in your URL
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
And simply add them to another URL

Comment: Don't I need to get the $url first to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can try to get it $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

Answer (score 0):

You can create a quick and easy function which does this:

```
<?php
function addParam(Array $param, Array &$parameters)
{
    $parameters = array_merge($_GET,$param);

}

function makeUrl(Array $parameters)
{
    return $page . '?' . http_build_query($parameters);
}

//Used like this
$itemid = 1;
addParam(array('itemid',$itemid),$parameters);
addParam(array('rel',$rel),$parameters);
?>
<a href="<?php echo makeUrl("/",$parameters); ?>">Go here</a>
```

See [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query)